# Where is footer.vm used in Confluence?

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin

I am new to Confluence, and I am playing with it (version 5.10.7).

I am reading the system's code, and I am unable to find out where footer.vm is used. Here is where common-header.vm (another file in Confluence) is used: Inside main.vmd, there is the following line:

```
#parse("/decorators/includes/common-header.vm")
```

I am not able to find similar code to use footer.vm.

Comment: Got a downvote. Confused. Did I ask a wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

`footer.vm` contains following code:

```
## Page footer for main and admin decorators.
#parse("/decorators/includes/footer-content.vm")
```

Above code contains the content of the footer.

For example in `printable.vmd` you can find following which parse the footer file:

```
#parse ("/decorators/includes/footer.vm")
```

However, if you want to change the content of the footer you need to change `/confluence/decorators/includes/footer-content.vm` file.

Also I would recommend you to take a look at this [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-edit-the-footer-in-confluence-163415355.html) and ensure that you don't break the EULA.

Comment: Sale, thanks for your help! Do you know which vmd file uses 'printable.vmd'? Basically, I need to see how changes to 'footer.vm' or 'footer-content.vm' can be displayed in regular confluence pages? I tested changes to these two files, but I am not able to see the changes in regular Confluence pages.

Comment: Have you restarted Confluence after changes? Also may I know what exactly you want to change?

Comment: Saleh, I modified printable.vmd by adding '<span>test text</span> just beneath <body>. Restarted Confluence. Not able to see any changes in display. Thanks.

Comment: Oh gotcha! These files are Velocity Template files, in order to edit that, please take a look at https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-architecture/confluence-internals/velocity-template-overview Also, https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/customizing-the-login-page-163938553.html is another good example of how to edit a vm file ;-)

Comment: Saleh, thanks for your follow up with me! Thanks for the info!